# $u$-channel in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, scattering, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

I have two questions regarding the $u$-channel in Feynman diagrams.

$\textbf{Question 1:}$ Suppose I have a $\gamma\gamma\to\bar{\nu}_{\mu}\nu_{\mu}.$ One of the diagrams will look as one of the following:[image]

Is there a difference between these two? Are both allowed? If so, which is the correct one?

$\textbf{Question 2:}$ Is there any physical difference between, say, a t-channel, and a u-channel? For instance, in Möller scattering, what is the physical difference between these two?

[image]

It seems to me that these both describe the same physics: an electron gives off a photon, which is absorbed by another electron, which causes them both to be deflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same diagrams and account for the possible combinations which gives back the combinatorial factor when evaluating transition amplitudes.

Since they describe the same physical process but are described by slightly different formulas, they have to be "summed coherently", which just gives back some numerical factor called **symmetry factor**